# How to recursively create a new list of positions given a list and a value?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to create a function that takes in two parameters, a list and a value, and returns a new list that is the index positions of the given list that contain the given value. Helper functions are allowed for keeping count

I've tried using the index() function to add to the list but every time i go through recursively the 1 is at a different index than it is in the original given list.

```
def position(mylist, x):
    if x in mylist:
        return [mylist.index(x)] + position(mylist[1:], x)
    else: 
        return []
```

I need `position([1,2,3,4,1,1], 1)` to return `[0,4,5]` but it returns [0, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0]

Comment: Welcome To SO! It helps if you make code fences for the code you are doing. I suppose that is why it got down voted. Thanks!!

Comment: Add an additional parameter with default value, e.g. `shift=0`. The parameter is meant to hold the number of elements removed from `mylist` to add it to `index`.

Comment: Thank you Michael I was able to make it work using a third input parameter as a counter!

Answer (score 0):

A function that returns the position(s), if any, of a value `x`, could be:

```
def position(mylist, x):
    return [i for i, e in enumerate(mylist) if e == x]
```